# Why am I getting EOFException when connecting to a specific website using Jsoup?

Tags: java, jsoup

I'm trying to get some  data from this website http://www.mof.gov.cn/, and I keep on getting EOFException:

The connect command is very basic:
`Jsoup.connect("http://www.mof.gov.cn/").ignoreContentType(true).userAgent("Mozilla/5.0(Windows NT 6.1; rv:23.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/23.0").timeout(30000).get();`

The EOFException is that:

```
java.io.EOFException
at java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream.readUByte(GZIPInputStream.java:207)
at java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream.readUShort(GZIPInputStream.java:197)
at java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream.readUInt(GZIPInputStream.java:189)
at java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream.readTrailer(GZIPInputStream.java:179)
at java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream.read(GZIPInputStream.java:94)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:256)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:317)
at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:90)
at org.jsoup.helper.DataUtil.readToByteBuffer(DataUtil.java:124)
at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:464)
at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:410)
at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.execute(HttpConnection.java:164)
at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.get(HttpConnection.java:153)
at com.staging.Crawfinance.main(Crawfinance.java:30)
```

Any idea why? Many thanks.

Comment: Maybe it's timing out or the server is resetting your connection...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try this with a valid charset name :

> Document doc = Jsoup.parse(new URL("http://www.mof.gov.cn/").openStream(), "UTF-8", "http://www.mof.gov.cn/");

Comment: Works great! Thanks! I just change the charset to be GBK, it work fine